# Could not replace dead cassandra node due to Host ID collision issue

Tags: cassandra

We have installed cassandra 3.9 in 6 EC2 nodes. One of the node died due to some reasons and showed DN status in nodetool status. So i am trying to replace the node based on the instructions provided here.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/topo_changes.html#replacing-a-dead-node

in short using the -Dcassandra.replace_address and -Dcassandra.replace_address_first_boot when starting the cassandra. However, this does not seems to be working.

I am receiving the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Host ID collision between active endpoint
```

I tried to remove the node using nodetool remove as well, and tried again. But, whatever i tried seems to be in vain.

The machine is not the seed node. I want to to start it directly without using replace, but would definitely want to know the reason why replace isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, you definitely need to remove the problem node.

> I tried to remove the node using nodetool remove as well, and tried again. But, whatever i tried seems to be in vain.

Sometimes `nodetool removenode` appears to do nothing or even hangs.  At this point, I'd suggest the following:

1. Execute your removenode command.
2. After a minute or two, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to return to your command prompt.
3. Verify that removenode is actually doing something:

`$ nodetool removenode status`

4. Expedite the removal process with the "force" command:

`$ nodetool removenode force`

Once that node is gone, try replacing it again.  Note, if the IPs are the same, you may still need to use the `replace_address` line in the cassandra-env.sh.

Comment: Hi Aaron, After struggling to replace and not even able to start, it seems the host id with old machine updated in system tables. So, i had to do a hard delete of <data_folder>/system/*. And then, could start with replace_address.

Comment: Not sure how elegant this is, after throughly looking into logging and struggling for hours with the same issue, i did this and it worked out..

Comment: Hi Aaron, i do have other question regarding cassandra, if you have few minutes